# C# - Storing datatable values in an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable

I want to store the result of select query in an array in C#. Please tell me how to get datatable values and store in an array. My select query result contains n rows and only one column.

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 private void getData()
        {
            SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("data source='c:\\northwind.sdf'; mode=Exclusive;");
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select [Unit Price] from Products", conn);
            DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtSource);
            DataRow[] dr = new DataRow[dtSource.Rows.Count];
            dtSource.Rows.CopyTo(dr, 0);
            double[] dblPrice= Array.ConvertAll(dr, new Converter<DataRow , Double>(DataRowToDouble));

        }

        public static double DataRowToDouble(DataRow dr)
        {
            return Convert.ToDouble(dr["Unit Price"].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Replace `type` with the data type of your single column (e.g. `int`, `string`, ...) and `myField` with the name of your single column.

```
var myArray = (from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
               select row.Field<type>("myField")).ToArray();
```

Using the magic of C#'s generics and type inference, your array will automatically have the correct data type (e.g. `int[]`, `string[]`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable mydt = new DataTable();
ArrayList aLrows = new ArrayList();

foreach (DataRow dataRow in mydt.Rows)
{
  aLrows.Add(string.Join(";", dataRow.ItemArray.Select(item => item.ToString)));
}
```